# Getting Most Recent Results when Searching for Podcast Episodes in the Spotify API

Tags: spotify

I pretend to get the most recent episodes for when their title or description contain some text like, for example, "tim ferriss". Is this possible? I managed to search for certain strings with [Search for Item](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search) option but I can't figure out how to sort the results by publication datetime. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Python but I just wanted to know if sorting was possible. Many thanks for your answer below!

Comment: No problem,  I will try to support the Python version too when I return home later.

Comment: I added `Python` demo. If you like it, please vote for my answers. It will make me happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Search for Item`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search) API has no sort option.

So you have to sort at the client side by your own logic.

You did not specify the language option.
I made a demo code by `node.js`

##### Demo Code

```js
const express = require("express")
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require("cors")
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

// Credential
CLIENT_ID = "<your Client ID>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your Client Secret>"
PORT = 3000 // it is located in Spotify dashboard's Redirect URIs, my port is 3000, should be replace your Port
REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback` // my case is 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
SCOPE = [
    'user-read-private'
]

// Get Access Token
const getToken = async (code) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            data = new URLSearchParams({
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
                'code': code
            }),
            config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: CLIENT_ID,
                    password: CLIENT_SECRET
                }
            })
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.access_token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
}

// Get Episodes by query
const getEpisodes = async (token, query) => {
    try {
        let offset = 0
        let next = 1
        const limit = 50;
        const episodes = [];

        const encodeString = encodeURI(query)
        while (next != null) {
            const resp = await axios.get(
                url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${encodeString}&type=episode&limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`,
                config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    }
                })
            for(const item of resp.data.episodes.items) {
                if(item?.name != null) {
                    episodes.push({
                        name: item.name,
                        release_date: item.release_date,
                        external_urls: item.external_urls.spotify,
                        duration_ms: item.duration_ms,
                        type: item.type,
                        id : item.id,
                        // <extension data>
                        // audio_preview_url: item.audio_preview_url,
                        // description: item.description,
                        // html_description: item.html_description,
                        // images : item.images,
                    })
                }
            }
            offset = offset + limit
            next = resp.data.episodes.next
        }
        // After sort by release date
        return Promise.resolve(episodes.sort((a,b) => Date.parse(b.release_date) - Date.parse(a.release_date)));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
}

// login URL
app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPE}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
})

// Call back URL
app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const code = request.query["code"]
    getToken(code)
        .then(access_token => {
            getEpisodes(access_token,"tim ferriss")
                .then(episodes => {
                    // For file save
                    const data = JSON.stringify(episodes);
                    fs.writeFileSync('simple_results.json', data);

                    // For browser displaying 
                    return response.send({
                        'Total episodes length: ': episodes.length,
                        'Episodes': episodes
                    });
                })

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        })
})


// start express server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`)
})
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install axios express cors fs
```

##### Run the server

```
node demo.js
```

##### Login and Get Episodes

The port number should be match your port number.

```
http://localhost:3000/user
```

##### Result

[image]

If you want to see full data, remove commend-out code in `getEpisodes()`

```
episodes.push({
    name: item.name,
    release_date: item.release_date,
    external_urls: item.external_urls.spotify,
    duration_ms: item.duration_ms,
    type: item.type,
    id : item.id,
    // <extension data>
    audio_preview_url: item.audio_preview_url,
    description: item.description,
    html_description: item.html_description,
    images : item.images,
})
```

##### Update - added Python demo

Save as `get-episodes.py` file name.

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import quote
import numpy as np
import datetime as DT

# Set your Spotify API credentials as environment variables, it will pick by spotipy API
CLIENT_ID = "9d53d43408c04c089e58f6b615f44bf9"
CLIENT_SECRET = "96f14dc115644d83b8957b77fcface31"
PORT = 3000
REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:{0}/callback".format(PORT)

# Just this scope good enough to get user_recently_played API
scope = "user-read-recently-played"

# This API call raise web browser and ask user login for getting callback with Authorization Code flow
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id = CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI,
    scope = scope))

def get_episodes(query):
    try:
        offset = 0
        limit = 50
        episode_features_list = [
            "name",
            "release_date",
            "tag_new",
            "external_urls",
            "duration_ms",
            "type",
            "id",
            # <extension data>
            # "audio_preview_url",
            # "description",
            # "html_description",
            # "images",
        ]
        episode_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=episode_features_list)
        today = DT.date.today()
        two_week_ago = today - DT.timedelta(days = 14)
        while True:
            results = sp.search(q=quote(query), type='episode', offset=offset, limit=limit)
            for item in results['episodes']['items']:
                # Create empty dictionary
                episode_features = {}
                # Get metadata
                episode_features["name"] = item["name"]
                episode_features["release_date"] =  pd.to_datetime(item["release_date"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
                episode_features['tag_new'] = np.where(episode_features["release_date"] >= pd.to_datetime(two_week_ago, format='%Y-%m-%d'), True, False)
                episode_features["external_urls"] = item["external_urls"]["spotify"]
                episode_features["duration_ms"] = item["duration_ms"]
                episode_features["type"] = item["type"]
                episode_features["id"] = item["id"]
                # Concatenate the data frames
                item_df = pd.DataFrame(episode_features, index=[0])
                episode_df = pd.concat([episode_df, item_df], ignore_index=True)
            # Increment offset by the limit for the next API call
            offset += limit
            next = results['episodes']['next']
            if next is None:
                break
        return episode_df
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to upload to call get_episodes(): '+ str(e))

episodes = get_episodes("tim ferriss")
sorted_episodes = episodes.sort_values(by='release_date', ascending = False)
print(sorted_episodes)
```

##### Run the python demo

```
python get-episodes.py
```

##### Python Result

[image]

Comment: I assume I'd need to paginate through the results in order to get more than 20 but that will result in many request and I may probably hit a rate limit ... I'd be perfect if `tag:new` option just worked with episodes too

Comment: The default `limit` value is 20. It makes more calls if a large size of data. That is why I change 50. it is the maximum value. It makes just 3 API calls in the case of this query (147/50 = 3). I experienced getting 7000 songs but not happed call limit. I have no experience the `tag:new`. let me know your tested it.

Comment: @DanielGarcíaBaena, I updated to support tag:new column for within last 14 days episode.